React Native - App Lifecycle Events - Bringing the app to the foreground
I have a React Native mobile app. This mobile app loads a list of translated strings and dynamic strings from a remote API when the app initially starts. While the translated strings are unlikely to change, I anticipate the dynamic strings changing once or twice per day. I'm trying to understand what happens when someone moves the app to the background and later (maybe 30 minutes later, maybe days later) brings it to the foreground.
Is there an event that I can listen for to respond to the user bringing the app to the foreground?

On what OS?  iOS and Android will be totally different for a lot of these things.  On Android, that won't happen.  If the app is in the background for more than a few minutes, it will be killed and restarted the next time it's open, to preserve memory resources.  So it's not really an issue.  The correct way to deal with this is just to set a background job (in native Android you'd use WorkManager, I'm sure there's a react native wrapper for it) to download the strings once or twice a day and save them to a db for use.  Alternatively, you can use push messaging to tell your app when to download new strings by sending a push when they change.
